# mysql count not working properly?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am trying to count the total comments posted by single user. Here is the table structure of the `comments` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `PLD_COMMENT` (
   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,        
   `ITEM_ID` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
   `USER_ID` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
   `USER_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
   `COMMENT` longtext,
   `COMMENT_TITLE` varchar(255) default NULL,
   `COMMENT_RATING` tinyint(1) default '1', 
   `TYPE` int(11) NOT NULL, 
   `DATE_ADDED` timestamp NOT NULL 
       default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `IPADDRESS` varchar(15) default NULL,
   `STATUS` varchar(11) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is the table structure for `user` table

```
CREATE TABLE `pld_user`(
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `LOGIN` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `PASSWORD` varchar(46) NOT NULL,
    `LEVEL` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
    `RANK` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
    `ACTIVE` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
    `LAST_LOGIN` timestamp NOT NULL 
        default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `REGISTRATION_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `AUTH_IMG` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `AUTH_IMGTN` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `SUBMIT_NOTIF` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1', 
    `PAYMENT_NOTIF` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1', 
    `ADDRESS` varchar(255) default NULL, 
    `EMAIL` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `WEBSITE` varchar(255) default NULL, 
    `WEBSITE_NAME` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `INFO` varchar(255) default NULL, 
    `ANONYMOUS` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0', 
    `LANGUAGE` varchar(2) default NULL, 
    `AVATAR` varchar(100) default NULL,
    `ICQ` varchar(15) default NULL, 
    `AIM` varchar(255) default NULL, 
    `YIM` varchar(255) default NULL, 
    `MSN` varchar(255) default NULL, 
    `CONFIRM` varchar(10) default NULL,
    `NEW_PASSWORD` varchar(46) default NULL,
    `EMAIL_CONFIRMED` int(11) NOT NULL default '1', 
    `LNAME` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `CITY` varchar(255) default NULL, 
    `STATE` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `DOB` date default NULL,
    `UTYPE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
 COMMENT='Stores all the users with informations'
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT count(c.USER_ID) as total_commments_user , 
  c.*, u.NAME, l.TITLE as LINK_TITLE, u.AUTH_IMG
FROM `PLD_COMMENT` c
left outer join `PLD_USER` u ON (u.ID = c.USER_ID) 
left outer join `PLD_LINK` l ON (l.ID = c.ITEM_ID AND l.STATUS='2') 
WHERE c.TYPE = '1' 
  AND c.STATUS = '2' 
group by c.ID ORDER BY c.ID DESC LIMIT 0 , 3
```

When I run this query I got 1 in each row under `total_comments_user`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add all the columns you are selecting in the `SELECT` clause except the `c.USER_ID` to the `GROUP BY` clause, like this:

```
group by c.ID, c.otherfields, l.title,..
```

**EDIT:** I think the following will work properly:

```
SELECT count(c.USER_ID) as total_commments_user , 
       c.*, u.NAME, l.TITLE as LINK_TITLE, u.AUTH_IMG
FROM `PLD_COMMENT` c 
left outer join `PLD_USER` u ON (u.ID = c.USER_ID) 
left outer join `PLD_LINK` l ON (l.ID = c.ITEM_ID) 
group by c.ITEM_ID, c.USER_ID
ORDER BY c.USER_ID, l.ID
```

**Example:**
If you have the following sample data:

- **PLD_LINK:**

  ```
  ID   STATUS   TITLE    
  1      1      title1
  2      2      title2
  ```
- **PLD_USER:**

  ```
  ID     NAME
  8    Mahmoud
  9     Ahmed
  ```
- **PLD_COMMENT:**

  ```
  ID   ITEM_ID USER_ID   STATUS
  4      1        8        1
  5      1        8        1
  6      1        8        1
  7      2        8        2
  8      2        8        2
  9      1        9        1
  10     1        9        1
  ```

---

### Case 1: the user `Mahmoud` is  displayed twice:

Then, the previous query will give you the count of the comments for each User and for each item too, like this:

```
total_commments_user  ID  ITEM_ID   USER_ID   Name
         3            4      1         8     Mahmoud
         2            7      2         8     Mahmoud
         2            9      1         9      Ahmed
```

**Notice that the user `Mahmoud` is displayed twice with a different count, becouse he has different `Item_Id`**.

---

### Case 2: the user `Mahmoud` is diplayed only one time:

If you want to get the count of comments for each user for all items then you will need to group by only the `USER_ID` and you will got:

```
total_commments_user  ID  ITEM_ID   USER_ID   Name  
         5            4      1         8     Mahmoud
         3            9      1         9      Ahmed
```

**As you can see now the user `Mahmoud` is displayed only one time, becouse we ingonred `Item_Id`**.

You can then filter by status or what ever.

Comment: why should i need to do this? if i have 20 fields except the c.USER_ID i have to put them all in group by?

Comment: i did what you asked me to do ... here is the query and it is still returning the same thing: [code] SELECT count(c.USER_ID) as total_commments_user , u.NAME, l.TITLE as LINK_TITLE, u.AUTH_IMG

FROM `PLD_COMMENT` c left outer join `PLD_USER` u ON (u.ID = c.USER_ID) 
left outer join `PLD_LINK` l ON (l.ID = c.ITEM_ID AND l.STATUS='2') 
WHERE c.TYPE = '1' AND c.STATUS = '2' 

group by u.NAME, LINK_TITLE, u.AUTH_IMG  ORDER BY c.ID DESC LIMIT 0 , 3 [/code]

Comment: @HananAli, unfortunately, becouse all fields that you are selecting in your `SELECT` statements, that are not enclosed in an aggregate function like `COUNT` or `SUM`, have to be added in the `GROUP BY` clause too. This is becouse `Count` is returns a single value, but we have a lot of values for each fields in the select statements.

Comment: can you please help me what should be the best way to achieve this? I shall be very thankful to you for this regard

Comment: @HananAli, Sorry I didn't see the `JOIN` clasue, but i can't understand your tables' structures and the joins between them but try to Group by the Id of the joined table or the field that the join is based on it and the counted id something like `Groub by c.USER_ID, u.ID` this should work, BTW: your tables need to be normalized, this is a bad design and defficult to work with

Comment: actually these are not designed by me, i am using an open source phpLd so need some customization there and i am using its own structure to go ahead. anyhow thanks, i will struggle bit to find the solution.

Comment: As you explained that Mahmoud, Mahmoud and Ahmed are being display and you see that total_commments_user is different for each time Mahmoud is being display, i need the total_commments_user same for each time Mahmoud is being display, other than i have solved the same

Comment: @HananAli, then remove the `Item_Id` from the group by it will become `group by c.User_ID`, the user `Mahmoud` was displayed twice becouse he has two different `Item_Id`, but if we just group by `User_Id` the item id will be ignored and mahmoud would be displayed only one time, I already mentioned that in my answer, but i edited it to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the group by clause will group the count by all of the select criteria.  So due to different l.title values you will get only a count of user id by l.title.

Basically you make one of your columns your select count.  i.e

```
(select count(*) from tables where) as totalcount
```

The return is going to give you the count for every instance of that user id and it will show that count in every row for that userid.   you will have to add the conditional clauses to make the subselect only look at the rows relevant to that userid.

Comment: so what should i do in order to get all comments by a user? Do i use sub-query instead of this? Please guide