# INNER JOIN 3 tables and count them

Tags: sql, inner-join

Hey i need to make a count on a few tables where i have to join them.

```
string strSQL = @"SELECT 3.Text
               FROM  1 WHERE 1.ProductID=@ProductID AND 1.CustomerID=@CustomerID AND 3.Text=@text AND 1.Date BETWEEN '@DateFrom' and '@DateTo' INNER JOIN 
               2 ON 1.ID = 2.1ID INNER JOIN 
               3 ON 2.3ID = 3.ID";
```

---

```
    SqlCommand objCMD = new SqlCommand(strSQL);

    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ProductID;
    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CategoryID;
    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CustomerID;
    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@text", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = text;
    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateFrom;
    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@DateTo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTo;
    return objData.GetData(objCMD, _Con).Rows.Count;
```

I keep geting a error there says *There is an incorrect syntax near `INNER`*,

**Where I am going wrong???**

Comment: I surely hope you haven't named your tables `1` and `2` and `3`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `JOIN` clause before the join condition like this:

```
SELECT t3.Text, COUNT(ID)
FROM  Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID
WHERE t1.ProductID = @ProductID 
      AND t1.CustomerID = @CustomerID 
      AND t3.Text=@text 
      AND t1.Date BETWEEN '@DateFrom' and '@DateTo' 
GROUP BY t3.TEXT
```

Comment: @Rene, suppose you want to get the `count(ID)` so it would be one value, but for the selected `t3.Text` has many values so you have  to tell sql to group the count by the `t3.Text`, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098265/mysql-count-not-working-properly/9098323#9098323

Comment: Ok now it just say "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string" what have i done wrong now? sry to boder you so much im new to this

Comment: @Rene, since `t1.Date` is defined in your table as `date` or `datetime`, you will need to cast `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo` to the corresponding date type something like: `t1.Date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(@DateFrom) and STR_TO_DATE(@DateTo)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `stringSql` is absolutely wrong.
You can't mix `WHERE/ON` operator in that way.

You have to correct it and make something like this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 1 INNER JOIN 2 
  ON 1.ID = 2.ID 
INNER JOIN 3 
  ON 2.ID = 3.ID 
WHERE 
  1.ProductID=@ProductID 
    AND 
  1.CustomerID=@CustomerID 
    AND 
  3.Text=@text 
    AND 
  1.Date BETWEEN '@DateFrom' and '@DateTo'
```

Edit: I hope that `1` and `2` (tables name) and so on are only for this example, because isn't a good idea to call entities in that way...

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `SELECT 3.Text` with `SELECT COUNT(*)` to get the number of rows directly.